# Problems with trying to use a bool in 2 classes

Tags: c#, xna, boolean

I'm trying to add a shield that is active for a limited to my game but right now it doesn't work for some reason and I just can't figure out why.

First, this is the shield class:

```
class Shield : SpriteGameObject
{
protected float counter;
protected float limit;
public bool isShieldOn;
protected bool startCounting;

public Shield(int layer = 0, string id = "") : base("Sprites/spr_shield", layer, id) 
{
    counter = 0;
    limit = 5;
    isShieldOn = false;
    startCounting = false;
}

public override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    //Stuff here

    while (startCounting)
        counter += (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;

    if (counter >= limit)
    {
        isShieldOn = false;
        counter = 0;
        startCounting = false;
    }

    Player player = GameWorld.Find("player") as Player;
    if (this.visible && this.CollidesWith(player))
    {
        isShieldOn = true;
        startCounting = true;
        this.visible = false; GameEnvironment.AssetManager.PlaySound("Sounds/snd_shieldcollected");
    }
}
}
```

Right now the game freezes when the player touches the shield but that has something to do with the while statement that contains the counter. I don't know why but first let me explain the isShieldOn bool I've been having problems with.

Here is where is use the isShieldOn bool:

```
class Health : GameObjectList
{
Shield shield;

public Health(int layer = 3, string id = "") : base(layer, id) 
{
    //Stuff here

    shield = new Shield(1, "shields");
}

public override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    base.Update(gameTime);
    if (shield.isShieldOn == false)
    {
        //Remove health
    }
}
}
```

At the moment the shield works when I just give it the value true in the constructor. But it doesn't become true if I try to assign it the if statement in the Update method of the Shield class. I'm 100% sure the if statement is performed because the shield does disappear when touched (this.visible = false) and the soundeffect plays.

If you have any ideas on how to fix this problem I'd be really thankfull, also if you have an idea on how to fix the timer.

Comment: Update gets called each frame. You want the `while` to be an `if` instead. You will also want to cache the result of `Find("player")` in a member (assuming its always the same object), because finding objects is expensive. (I'm not actually familiar with xna but I'm pretty sure all I said is relevant)

Comment: Well, his Find("player") method is of his own creation (or an imported library), so whether that is expensive is impossible to tell without seeing the actual code that is executed inside that method. You are however right in the 'while to if'-thing.

Comment: @BjarkeSøgaard I see. However even if it is cached and retrieved in O(1), saving a direct reference where it is needed is surely faster. 0 operations are better than `k` operations :P . Anyways, this was just an extra note for OP

Comment: @SimpleVar Certainly, I see what you mean. But generally when someone say something is "expensive", they usually mean in such a scale that it has a visible impact on the application as a whole.

Comment: You should replace "while" to "if" to remove infinity loop, but if you cannot do that it mean that your game logic is somewhere wrong. First of all say please what your shield should do? And why you check it with your player to meke it invisible?

Comment: @BjarkeSøgaard I was assuming `Find` is similar to `FindObject` in the Unity framework. I did say I'm not familiar with xna as a disclaimer :)

Comment: @SimpleVar Oh in that case, my bad. I am not familiar with the Unity framework, so I wasn't aware of the FindObject method from that :)

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
while (startCounting)
    counter += (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
```

to

```
counter += (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
```

in your Update method().

Comment: You don't want to *always* count the shield-timer. Only when it is active. You want the `while` to be an `if`, that is all.